# What is the best way to update a one table from another in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join, exists

I have 2 tables the first one is the product-page **visited**

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| idproduct  | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| logdate    | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| idmagasin  | int(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| idenseigne | int(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| commanded  | int(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And the second one is the product **commanded**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| idproduct   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| idenseigne  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| idmagasin   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| ingredients | tinytext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| date        | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

How can i update the column **commanded** in product_visited , `if product_visited.idproduct = product_commanded.idproduct and product_visited.logdate = product_commanded.date`

i'm confused to use **inner join** or **exists**

I want to `update product_visited.commanded = 1`  when the value of `logdate` and `idproduct` exists in product_commanded, **it will mean the product visited is commanded too**

Comment: You want to join the tables, using exists won't let you use any of the fields from the subquery to update your main table.

Comment: You put the predicate conditions you mention into a where clause in your update statement. But to get complete SQL, you have to tell us what value (or expression which can be evaluated) to which you want to update the column `commanded`.

Comment: @RichBenner i read the documentaton for "join", but when we join, can we update the table in the same time?

Comment: BTW, all your `id_*` fields should have an index (simple or unique, I let you choose). It'll speed up your query

Comment: @parik,  depends on what database vendor you use. Syntax to do this is slightly different for SQL Server, mySql, Oracle...

Comment: @CharlesBretana yes you are right i edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
Update product_visited pv
    set commanded = 1
    Where exists (Select 1
                  from product_commanded pc
                  where pv.idproduct = pc.idproduct and pv.logdate = pc.date
                 );
```

Comment: I can't vote now, thanks a lot, it's exactly what i searched

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've made guesses with the join fields but you're after something like this;

```
UPDATE pv
SET pv.Commanded = 1
FROM Product_Visited pv
JOIN Product_Commanded pc
    ON pv.logdate = pc.date
    AND pv.idproduct = pc.id
```

The inner join means that you're only going to update records in Product_Visited where there are matching rows in Product_Commanded based on the join predicates you give it.

Note: this is a SQL Server answer. May or may not work in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to update `commanded` whenever a record exists for same product in `commanded` table?

in any database:

```
Update product_visited set commanded = 1
Where exists(Select * from product_commanded
             where product_id = product_visited.Product_id)
```

Comment: This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

Comment: @Gordon, yes, I started with different code that would not have been same in mySQL

Comment: @Gordon, (and @parik), do you need the predicate on `logdate` in the Exists subquery?